# ADO.NET Entity Data Model BUG

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a project in visual studio ultimate 2010 (MVVM) and database, in SQLITE.

Everything worked fine, but now I have a problem with the ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

I searched for information about this and have not found much .. **Every time I want to open the wizard, it just closes.**

I think I should reinstall Visual Studio, but before doing so if anyone has had this error before and know what can be, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Go to the Windows Event log and see why it's crashing.

Comment: Or listen to this brilliant answers and just start deleting files without knowing what they do...

Comment: I've found this can be a bug with third party data adapters being left in strange states.  Open your `View > Server Explorer` and remove your third-party data connections. Then, try opening the wizard again.

Comment: @GeorgeJohnston I did what you told me, then try to modify the connection and I got this error: An exception occurred in the type initializer for 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory'...

Then I reinstall System.Data.SQLite and the problem was solved. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: @wpfc I re-added my answer below as it solved your problem.  Thanks,George

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found this can be a bug with third party data adapters being left in strange states.  Open your `View > Server Explorer` and remove your third-party data connections. Then, try opening the wizard again.

Comment: I did what you told me, then try to modify the connection and I got this error: An exception occurred in the type initializer for 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory'... Then I reinstall System.Data.SQLite and the problem was solved. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem with VS 2013 (Entity Model Wizard disappearing). I solved it by first uninstalling the MySQL .NET/Connector (I had 6.8.3) and installing it back, and then retrying the wizard. Wizard completes and I could select tables etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the following file

c:\users\myusername\appdata\roaming\microsoft\visualstudio\10.0\SeverExplorer\DefaultView.SEView.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a web application such as through MVC check the `AttachDBFilename` in `web.config` for characters such as |.

I had the same issue and was unable to resolve it by removing connections from Server Explorer.

I attached a visual studio debugger to visual studios.

Turned on CLI exceptions and turned off Just my Code.

I then saw the hidden exception.

The wizard was throwing an exception with the message "`Invalid Character in Path`" in `System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(string path, bool checkAdditional).`

The value of path was `"|DataDirectory|\\aspnet-Mvs4Dummy1-20140402113853.mdf".`

I realised that this was the database that visual studios had automatically generated with my MVC application and that the offending character was probably the `'|'` symbol.

So I performed a Grep search of my directory and found that this was being stored in my web.config in this apparently unsupported format.

I changed the entry to a full local path and the wizard stopped disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

Open VS,
View->Server Explorer and delete connections under the data connection files.
I had already this error before and solve it doing like this.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for VS2015 was:

Install MySQL.NET Connector 6.9.8 to replace 6.9.5.

I already has installed MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.6 and had got the appropratiate MySQL NuGet packages (MySQL.Data, MySQL.Data.Entity.EF6, MySQL.Web).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing some steps below:
1/ Open "Server Explorer" window in Visual Studio
2/ Delete all Connections under "Data Connections" sections
3/ Then, Add the ADO.net Entity Data Model as normal